# Whether to comment or answer

Tags: discussion, support

I commented on a question which provided link to the same issue and the OP was able to solve his issue. So now whether I should post it as answer or let the OP give his own version.

I'm confused as I didn't solve the issue but just guided OP to proper answer. Whether it's correct to post my own answer?
Or rather should I include the reference link in my answer.

Here is the [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284933/whats-difference-between-ignore-sticky-posts-and-post-not-in-sticky-post?noredirect=1#comment422026_284933) to the question

Any suggestions please

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has since been closed as a duplicate. If you run across a question that you've seen elsewhere on the site, you can use the `flag` option to bring it to the communities attention and others can decide if it is indeed a duplicate question or if it stands on it's own. Once flagged as duplicate, a comment will be automatically generated alerting OP of the possible duplication and it's up to them to either remove their question, allow the community to close their question, or edit their question to make it distinct than the linked possible duplicate.

Marking an answer as duplicate is as follows. Clicking the `flag` link underneath the question then clicking the `duplicate of` radio button. This will allow you to paste the URL of the duplicate question.

While you get no points for pointing out the duplicate, it may help the original question asker find their solution faster and overall helps keep the community cleaner.

Comment: I was wondering this only that how do questions get marked duplicate.. Will make sure to do the required on any future questions. Thanks!!!